# What exactly is a datatype?

Tags: language-agnostic, types

I understand what a datatype is (intuitively). But I need the formal definition. I don't understand if it is a **set** or it's the names 'int' 'float' etc. The formal definition found on wikipedia is confusing.

> In computer programming, a data type is a classification identifying one of various types of data, such as floating-point, integer, or Boolean, that determines the possible values for that type; the operations that can be done on values of that type; the meaning of the data; and the way values of that type can be stored.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: What do you understand about the word "type"? Doesn't matter if it's in a programming context.

Comment: Yes, a definition that uses the words in the definition is not particularly useful: *"In computer programming, a **data type** is a classification identifying one of various **types** of **data**, such as floating-point, integer, or Boolean, that determines the possible values for that type..."*

Comment: @BoltClock A type of something is a 'variety' of something .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep.  What that's saying is that a data type has three pieces:

1. The various possible values.  So, for example, an eight bit signed integer might have -127..128.  This of that as a set of values V.
2. The operations: so an 8-bit signed integer might have `+`, `-`, `*` (multiply), and `/` (divide).  The full definition would define those as functions from V into V, or possible as a function from V into float for division.
3. The way it's stored -- I sort of gave it away when I said "eight bit signed integer".  The other detail is that I'm assuming a specific representation by the way I showed the range of values.

You might, if you're into object oriented programming, notice that this is very much like the definition of a class, which is defined by the storage used by each object, adn the methods of the class.  Providing those parts for some arbitrary thing, but not inheritance rules, gives you what's called an *abstract data type*.

**Update**

@Appy, there's some room for differences in the formalities.  I was a little subtle because it was late and I was suddenly uncertain if I'd assumed one's complement or two's complement -- of course it's two's complement.  So interpretation is included in my description. Abstractly, though, you'd say it is a algebraic structure T=(V,O) where V is a set of values, O a set of functions from V into some arbitrary type -- remember '==' for example will be a function eq:V × V → {0,1} so you can't expect every operation to be into V.

Comment: @ Charlie Thanks for the answer :)                                       So can I say it this way . The word 'datatype' represents a set       **{ {range of values for data} , {functions that can be performed on data } , how_to_store_data }**

Comment: You forgot a point . **4. The interpretation placed on this internal representation.** (_this_ refers to point 3)  .  I came across this a minute ago in an article on Datatypes .

Answer (score 0):

I can define it as a classification of a particular type of information. It is easy for humans to distinguish between different types of data. We can usually tell at a glance whether a number is a percentage, a time, or an amount of money. We do this through special symbols %, :, and $.

Basically it's the concept that I am sure you grock. For computers however a data type is defined and has various associated attributes, like size, like a definition keywork (sometimes), the values it can take (numbers or characters for example) and operations that can be done on it like add subtract for numbers and append on string or compare on a character, etc. These differ from language to language and even from environment to env. (16 - 32 bit ints/ 32 - 64 envs./ etc).

If there is anything I am missing or needs refining please ask as this is fairly open ended.

Comment: @ MahdeTo Thanks for the answer :)                                          So what you are basically trying to say is datatype is a set of rules in a language to represent a particular data ? Please see my comment on Charlies post and also reply to it :)