# Do "basic datatypes" and "built-in datatypes" mean the same?

Tags: language-agnostic, types

I recently came across a definition of a primitive data type (on wikipedia) ..
That it is either of the two -
1) A built-in datatype
2) A basic datatype

What is the difference between two ?
Can you give examples which clearly explain the difference :)
Thanks :)

Comment: I have a feeling that it depends on the particular language . Is it so ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly is a datatype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653116/what-exactly-is-a-datatype)

Comment: @Code Gray .. I asked this question after understanding "What exactly is a datatype" . The terminology is not so clear . I want to know the difference between the two terms .

Comment: Yes, that's what a duplicate is. A second question that you asked, where the first question encompasses the domain of the second question.

Answer (score 0):

Built in data types are often more less technically referred as basic data types.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Can you tell me what is **string** datatype in C++ and Java ?